# Python - Does iterating a generator expression impact the order of iterating another generator expression?

Tags: python, nlp, iterator, generator

I am iterating two different generators using two different for loops. But i could see that the iteration through one generator expression is impacting the order of iteration of another generator expression.

Though I understand and hope that this is impossible, but not sure why I am experiencing this weird behaviour.

```
we=KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('../input/nlpword2vecembeddingspretrained/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary='True')


data1=(['this','is','an','example','text1'],['this','is','an','example','text2'],....)

data2=(['test data1','test data2'],['test data3','test data4'],....)

txt_emb=(sum([we[token] for token in doc if token in we.key_to_index])/len(doc) for doc in data1)

phr_emb=([sum([we[token] for token in phrase.split(' ') if token in we.key_to_index])/len(phrase.split(' ')) for phrase in phrases]for phrases in data2)

for i in txt_emb:
    print(i)
    break
for j in phr_emb:
    print(j)
    break
```

**txt_emb :**

([-0.06002714  0.00999211  0.0358354 ....],..........[0.07940271 -0.02072765 -0.03981323...])

**phr_emb:**

([array([-0.13269043,0.03266907,...]),array([0.04994202,0.15716553,...])],

[array([-0.06970215,0.01029968,...]),array([0.02503967,0.13970947,...])],.......)

Here txt_emb is a generator expression with each iterable being a list.

The phr_emb is a generator expression with each iterable being a list and each list containing varying number of arrays(say 2-6).

When I iterate txt_emb first as in above code, i get the first element(list at index 0) of txt_emb which is as expected. Similarly when I iterate through phr_emb, i expect to get the first element(list at index 0), but I get the second element(list at index 1).

Similarly if I continue to iterate txt_emb again, i get the third element(list at index 2) rather than getting the element at index 1 of txt_emb, as I have iterated txt_emb only once before this.

I face similar issues when i zip the two generator expression txt_emb and phr_emb and try iterate through it.

I am running all this in kaggle notebook.But if I iterate both the generator expressions seperately in different cells of the notebook then I get the elements in order as expected.

Comment: There are no generators anywhere in your code, as far as I can tell. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: The answer to your question depends entirely on the generators being iterated upon. There won't inherently be any connection between your two iterations, but it's possible for the implementations of the generators to interact in some way.

Comment: @Blckknght I'm not sure in what sense the word "generator" is being used here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga have made some amendments to the query.

Comment: If your `data1` and `data2` sequences are really static values like you show here, it seems unlikely that the generator expressions you make based on them would vary depending on the order you run the loops. Maybe looking things up in `we` has some kind of side effects, some times? We can't really guess, though I suppose there could be somebody with experience in the NLP library you're using.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for that... but would like to understand why this happens only during zip or two continuous iterations through the two generator expressions as shown in above eg but does not happen when iterated seperately, as I am using the same 'we' in all these cases

Comment: Are your `dataX` variables both generator expressions themselves? Because if they're both drawing on the same iterator (such as a file) that could explain your issue.

Comment: @Blckknght Awesome!!!This worked...dataX are both generator expressions by themselves and both were drawing data from many common generator expressions and source of all these generator expressions were the same - a dataframe column. I have created a generator expression of this column and used that expression to create the other generator expressions.

Comment: @Blckknght It would be really great if you can explain why this happens? Also now i had to create an additional expression for every of these expressions (including for the source data)so that dataX variables draw their data from different expressions. Is there any other alternative to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, this appears to be an issue with your two generator expressions pulling data from some other, shared iterator (probably another generator expression). When the first generator expression advances, it takes data from this third iterator, which makes it unavailable to the second generator expression.

You can recreate this issue with simpler code like this:

```
data = range(10) # our underlying data
data_iterator = iter(data) # our shared iterator, which could be a generator expression

doubles = (x * 2 for x in data_iterator) # first generator expression
squares = (x * x for x in data_iterator) # second generator expression

print(next(doubles), next(doubles), next(doubles)) # prints 0 2 4
print(next(squares), next(squares), next(squares)) # prints 9 16 25, not 0 1 4 as you might expect
```

If you take a few values from one of the generator expressions, the corresponding value will be skipped in the other one. That's because they're each advancing the shared `data_iterator` in the background, which only goes over each value from the list once.

The solution is either to create separate iterators for each of the generator (e.g. multiple versions of `data_iterator`, or if it's awkward or time consuming to recompute, to dump it into a sequence like a list, so it can be iterated upon repeatedly.

For instance, we could dump `data_iterator` into `data_list`, like this, and then build the generator expressions off the list:

```
data = range(10)
data_iterator = iter(data)
data_list = list(data_iterator)    # this can be iterated upon repeatedly

doubles = (x * 2 for x in data_list)
squares = (x * x for x in data_list)

print(next(doubles), next(doubles), next(doubles)) # prints 0 2 4
print(next(squares), next(squares), next(squares)) # prints 0 1 4 as expected
```

Now, storing the data in a list like that may take more memory than you want. One of the nice things about generators and generator expressions is the lazy computation that they allow. If you want to maintain that lazy computation approach and only need the a few values to be available to one generators before the other, because they're being consumed mostly in parallel (e.g. by `zip`), then `itertools.tee` may be just what you need.

```
import itertools

data = range(10)
data_iterator = iter(data)
data_it1, data_it2 = itertools.tee(data_iterator) # two iterators that will yield the same results

doubles = (x * 2 for x in data_it1)
squares = (x * x for x in data_it2)

for d, s in zip(doubles, squares):  # consume the values in parallel
    print(d, s)
```

The iterators that `tee` returns *can* still be used if you're planning on fully consuming one generator before starting on the other, but they're a lot less efficient in that situation (just dumping the whole intermediate iterator into a list is probably better).

Comment: That was helpful...
Also the generator expression dataX has 214K lists inside and the length of each list varies from 2 to 20 text elements. I am trying to convert this generator expression into a list, but the generator expression being really big takes a lot of time to convert into a list. Is there any option which would help this conversion to be both memory and time efficient. I have tried methods like list(dataX) and even multiprocessing using pool, but still it takes a lot of time. I have not been successful even once in converting the entire expression into a list. Can you please help

Comment: The only real reason I can imagine that you'd have severe performance problems on that scale of a problem (which is not absurdly huge) would be if you're running out of memory somewhere, and the program drags to a near halt as it starts trying to swap memory around. Or I suppose it could be the same issue you'd have with lazy generators if your code is just using some deeply sub-optimal algorithm somewhere. But in either case, I don't think there's a general solution. You should ask another question with more details of your actual computation, and maybe somebody can help you optimize it.